# CANNOT download Adobe AIR SDK using Safari

Tags: sdk, air

On my Mac Book Pro, you CANNOT download the Adobe AIR SDK from the Adobe site using Safari.

I have found this to be true for several months.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firefox instead to download the Adobe AIR SDK. It works!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Adobe's server, still happening today (Apr 18th, 2013). It doesn't send the appropriate binary content-type to the browser, so Safari tries to show the big 200 MB tbz2 file in the browser, as if it was a plain text file. This causes Safari to stall and show the "spinning beach ball of death", which in some cases even makes the OS unresponsive, leaving you with little choice but to turn off the computer holding the power button a few seconds. This is poor coding in Safari's part. Big text files (even if they're not really text files in this case) shouldn't bring down the browser and the OS.

Even though this is Adobe's fault for not sending the appropriate content-type, Safari could have fixed this problem in the fly, as Firefox does (it detects binary files even if the content-type is not correct). But it doesn't, and thus this problem happens.

Please vote in this bugbase report so Adobe fixes this:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3544775